Manga about a character who was reborn/reincarnated as a baby to an elf mother and a human father
I tried to find it multiple times, but was never able to, I can't remember any names related to the manga, but I can remember quite a bit of scenes that happened in the manga.
The MC was reborn/reincarnated as a baby to an Elf mother and a human father within a kingdom, the family is a noble one with a clan/family name, and even as a baby the MC noticed his elf mother was close to death after giving birth so he restored and stabilized her vitality so she wouldn't die.
The MC's family is a military family, and the MC's father, and grandfather is and was the general/commander of a strong army that fought on the front lines and defended the kingdom. The MC when he was born with great magic and his family was told he would become a genius Magician, also the MC's entire family loved him when he was born his father, his elf mother, and his grandfather especially, a few years later at a young age instead of a great Magician he was found out to be a genius Alchemist instead but I believe he was just hiding his magical powers I can't remember clearly.
I believe a bit later his Elf mother took him to meet his Elf family, he meets his Elf grandmother who absolutely adored him, some things happened and his grandmother took him to meet a very old ancestor elf/goddess/spirit he also accepts a mission his elf grandmother believes to be impossible to find an ancient Lost artifact I believe belonging to the elves, which he didn't have a hard time locating at all, I think it was a staff but not sure, he also finds a huge skeleton of an old slain dragon, later he encounters a lonely Azure dragon in a cave that I think he fights and defeats as well as befriends, she later goes with him to her dragon clan to find a special herb.
The clan was not happy about her return let alone with a human, things happened and they proposed a deal he helps them find their lost dragon king and they would give him the herb, he already had the skeleton so he returned it right away and won their trust and friendship. The leader gave him a horn that allowed him to summon the entire dragon clan, and the last thing I remember was his final family member I remember is his human grandmother, she is known in the kingdom as a peerless genius/talent her power is nearly unrivaled, and has the highest title in the military even leading her own special secret division, she is living on a holy mountain peak in a sacred temple.
When his father took him to meet her the MC meet another person I recall it were a pretty rude/aggressive/feisty loli girl who was also a dragon in human form, they even fought but the grandmother stopped them and she meet with her grandson for the first time. That's all the details I can remember, it's quite a lot I know lol if anyone can give the name I'll greatly appreciate it.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Also this would be a lot easier to read if it were broken up into paragraphs.

If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

"Magic Stone Gourmet：Eating Magical Power Made Me The Strongest" has a dryad mother, rather than an elf mother, but most other details don't match up. Prominently, no scene where he heals his mother - he doesn't "wake up" until he's 5, and she's perfectly fine.

Removed my answer, since it doesn't have the half-elf protagonist I thought there was.

some of it matches Heartwarming Isekai Reincarnation Days: Level Max, Item Carryover! I'm the Strongest Little Girl . but i think i remember reading the one where the baby heals the mother. too bad i cant remember the title or what happens in it.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

i read this one. the mc baby is appraised and is found to have extreme "spirit wings". one of their children was sent to the church before, so they say this time they will hide the fact that the child has these powers from the church. i think i remember the child coming back from the church wants to kill the new baby or something too?

Otherworldly Magical Daoist Priest, alternate titles of Daoist Magician From Another World or Magician from Another World.


On the cusp of attaining godhood, Daolin Zhang is slain by his enemies. However, it’s not his end since he is reborn, not just as another person, but in an entire new world! Instead of qi, spirit techniques, and martial arts, he awakens as Klay Draconic, a young boy in a realm of elves, dwarves, and sorcery. Klay masters this new type of magic in no time, and his quest for power earns him fame and enemies. Good thing he has a lifetime of experience to stay one step ahead of his foes!


Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you [edit] this to explain how this manga matches the details provided in the question?

I guess you are looking for "Reincarnated with the strongest system"

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe this work and explain how it matches the question?

It matches exactly, this is the premise of the story for this light novel

@RishabhAgarwal Can you [edit] the answer to go into more detail than just "it matches exactly"? Can you, for example, quote the story's synopsis?
